# Able to import module but cannot use function inside it

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a function called `learn` in a module called `lrn_proto`.

I use it at other script, I can import it, but I'm not able to use it's function, it works before. But right now its not working anymore, and I even didn't modify the source code.

Here is the source of `lrn_proto`:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import time
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..\\..\\..\\conf'))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..\\..\\writer\\mem_writer_proto'))
from cfg_exe import exe_loc as loc

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(loc.lib))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(loc.mem))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(loc.main))
import mem_writer as mw
import prototype_ui as ptui

def learn(src,keywords,type,identifier):
    if src == r'\exit':
        print('You have choose to exit this program, see you later.')
        sys.exit()
    elif src == r'\add':
        ptui.menu()
    temp = src.lower()
    for x in keywords:
        if x in temp:
            temp_k1 = list(temp.partition(x))
            try:
                temp_k1_t = list(str(temp_k1.index(x)))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            for b in temp_k1_t:
                temp_k = list([temp_k1.pop(int(b))])
            print('True\n')
            continue
        elif x not in temp:
            temp_k = list('')
            pass
    for x in type:
        if x in temp:
            temp_t1 = list(temp.partition(x))
            try:
                temp_t1_t = list(str(temp_t1.index(x)))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            for b in temp_t1_t:
                temp_t = list([temp_t1.pop(int(b))])
            print('True\n')
            continue
        elif x not in temp:
            temp_t = list('')
            pass
    for x in identifier:
        if x in temp:
            temp_i1 = list(temp.partition(x))
            try:
                temp_i1_t = list(str(temp_i1.index(x)))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            for b in temp_i1_t:
                temp_i = list([temp_i1.pop(int(b))])
            print('True\n')
            continue
        elif x not in temp:
            temp_i = list('')
            pass
    temp_kti = list(temp_k+temp_t+temp_i)
    act_patt = '|'.join(temp_kti)
    act = (''.join((re.split(act_patt,temp))).strip(' .'))
    print('Output:')
    print('Keywords: ',temp_k,'\nType: ',temp_t,'\nIdentifier: ',temp_i,'\nContent: ',act)
    mw.dict(title,type,keywords,identifier,actions)
```

I tried:
`from lrn_proto import learn`

It produce:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'learn' from 'lrn_proto'`

Then with
`import lrn_proto`,

It produce this while the function is being called:

`AttributeError: module 'lrn_proto' has no attribute 'learn'`

The weird things are Those produced error doesn't tell me whats wrong with my code.

I had already add all modules directory to `sys.path`

Did anyone can inform me what is the wrong of my code?
I had no idea about what's wrong with my code.

I'm using Python3 on Windows.

Kindly ask me if you need more info about this question.

Comment: Are you using any kind of virtual environment? Also can you try executing`python -i lrn_proto.py` and try to use the `learn` method?

Comment: @Borisu I didn't use any virtual environment, forgot to mention, I'm using Python on Windows, I have a linux machine , maybe I will take the linux machine for a test.